# show more than one item in each row in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to show more than one item in each row in the **jQuery datatable plug-in**
 for example I want show 5 items in each row .

any idea ?

I use fnrender function to customize table :

```
"aoColumns": [

                        { "sName": "ID",

                            "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                                var data = oObj.aData[0];
                                return "<table width=\"650\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"12\" style=\"line-height:18px;\"><tr><td align=\"right\" valign=\"top\" bgcolor=\"#F0F0F0\" dir=\"rtl\"><p><a href=\"data?id=" + data[0] + "\" class=\"linknormaltext\" ><span class=\"normaltext\"><span class=\"header3\">" + data[1] + "<br><span class=\"date\">: " + data[2] + "</span></span></span></a></p></td></tr> </table>";
                            }
                        }
                    ]
         });
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to have one item per column and have 5 columns rather than one column with 5 entries?